# Executable which opens itself in runtime

Tags: assembly, elf

I wrote a snippet of code in assembly which tries to open a file called "Main" (using the open system call) and change its first bit to 0.

I've compiled it and I named the final executable "Main". My goal was to change the executable "Main" during its runtime.

But, after calling the open system call I get a negative file descriptor, which means that the open failed.

Am I doing something wrong or there's no way to ask from an executable to open itself?

Answer (score 1):

> But, after calling the open system call I get a negative file descriptor

It is possible that your assembly code executing the open system call is incorrect.

Another likely possiblity is that you have something like [SELinux](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux), and the policy in effect prohibits writing to executables.

Run your program under `strace` (or an equivalent for your OS), and see what error the open system call returns.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a program, you cannot modify the executable file (it is locked by the system). You try something impossible.

Comment: "it is locked by the system" that is wrong on all `ELF` systems I am aware of (except possibly HP-UX, which OP is not very likely to be using).